# How do I remove brackets, quotes and commas from the output of random.sample (discord bot made with python)

Tags: python, discord.py

Here is a piece of my code

```
@client.command()
async def b(ctx):
  bishops = [
        'Bishop', 'Atomic Bishop', 'Lite Bishop', 'Crowding Bishop','Phantom Bishop', 'Sweeping Bishop', 'Ghost Bishop', 'Super Bishop','Murderous Bishop', 'Castler Bishop', 'Princess', 'Bouncing Bishop'
  ]
  embed = discord.Embed(title="Random Bishops", description=random.sample(bishops, 2))
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

And the output looks like this [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs74r.png)

I want the code to output the same thing, but without the brackets or quotes. Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: `", ".join(ls)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join with Newline or with a seperator

```py
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Random Bishops", 
    description="\n".join(random.sample(bishops, 2))
    )
```